# How to only select rows containing [YYYY-MM-DD]?

Tags: r, string

I am looking at a data set with 35383 tweets, where I need to select only those containing a date like:

```
[2020-03-05] Power Plant Mines BTC 5.5/day
[2020-03-30] Bitcoin Is Making a Gradual Fall, May
[2020-04-04] Github Freezes Bitcoin Code in Arctic Ice
```

And not like;

```
Subject
POST FORMAT: YYYY-MM-DD SITE - HEADLINE « 1 2  All »
etc.
```

etc.

I have tried this, but with no luck:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_clean <- data_clean %>%
  filter(!data_clean[,1] == str_detect(data_clean[,1], pattern = "^/[[0-9]{4}.{1}[0-9]{2}.{1}[0-9]{2}/].{*}"))
```

I think that it might be the [] in the text that makes the problems?

I have added a photo of the output, where the first part with the numbers is dput(). dput() gives a very long and messy output, so below I have the 10 first rows of the data.

[Photo of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipx9G.png)

Comment: Could you add an example of your data using `dput(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your regex.
`/[` and `/]`, `/` is not an escape, you need to use `\\`.
You also shouldn't use `*` inside a quantifier, so instead of `{*}` use `.*`

```r
library(stringr)

txt <- c("[2020-03-05] Power Plant Mines BTC 5.5/day",
         "Bitcoin Is Making a Gradual Fall, May",
         "[2020-04-04] Github Freezes Bitcoin Code in Arctic Ice")


str_detect(txt, "^\\[[0-9]{4}.{1}[0-9]{2}.{1}[0-9]{2}\\].*")
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This `grep` function will do that

```
testinput <- c("[2020-03-05] Power Plant Mines BTC 5.5/day",
"[2020-03-30] Bitcoin Is Making a Gradual Fall, May",
"[2020-04-04] Github Freezes Bitcoin Code in Arctic Ice",
"POST FORMAT: YYYY-MM-DD SITE - HEADLINE « 1 2  All »")


grep("[\\d+]",testinput,value = T)


[1] "[2020-03-05] Power Plant Mines BTC 5.5/day"            
[2] "[2020-03-30] Bitcoin Is Making a Gradual Fall, May"    
[3] "[2020-04-04] Github Freezes Bitcoin Code in Arctic Ice"
```

you can remove the value = T if you just want the index and not the tweets themselves.